# Error with TukeyHSD

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data which looks like below and I try to perform ANOVA and check the differences between all the columns. How significantly they are different from each other etc.

```
df<- structure(list(color = structure(c(3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("B", "G", "R", "W"), class = "factor"), 
        type = 1:10, X1 = c(0.006605138, 0.001165448, 0.006975109, 
        0.002207839, 0.00187902, 0.002208638, 0.001199808, 0.001162252, 
        0.001338847, 0.001106317), X2 = c(0.006041392, 0.001639298, 
        0.006140877, 0.002958169, 0.002744017, 0.003107995, 0.001729594, 
        0.001582564, 0.001971713, 0.001693236), X3 = c(0.024180351, 
        0.002189061, 0.027377442, 0.002886651, 0.002816333, 0.003527908, 
        0.00231891, 0.001695633, 0.00212034, 0.001962923)), .Names = c("color", 
    "type", "X1", "X2", "X3"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

At first I perform ANOVA using the following command

```
 anovar= aov(type~.,df)
```

and then summary the outputs as follows:

```
summary(anovar)
```

Which so far so good and it performs just fine. However, when I try to perform the TukeyHSD, it seems like I have structure problem. The error is like below. I searched and i could not find any similar situation. Any comment would be appreciated

```
TukeyHSD(anovar)
# Error in rep.int(n, length(means)) : unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: X1
# 2: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: X2
# 3: In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: X3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it says in the description of the TukeyHSD documentation, the function creates a set of confidence intervals on the differences between the means of levels of a **factor** with the specified family-wise probability of coverage.

This means that you need to have factors in your data set in order to run it. So if you select the factor as follows it works:

```
> TukeyHSD(anovar, which = 'color') #color is the only categorical data

  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = type ~ ., data = df)

$color
     diff       lwr      upr     p adj
W-R 4.375 -1.465325 10.21532 0.1121168
```

You also get a warning that non factors X1, X2, X3 are ignored.

In order to print the TukeyHSD object just save it and use `plot`. There is a `plot` method (as well as a `print` method) for class TukeyHSD objects.

```
forplot <- TukeyHSD(anovar, which = 'color')
plot(forplot)
```

[image]

Comment: I was reading this web r-bloggers.com/anova-and-tukeys-test-on-r actually for me it is more important to check the differences between X1, X2 and X3 but they are ignored in this case!!!!, do you know how i can do it?

Comment: @Brain As you see in the link you provided, all the variables are factors there too. There is no way to use the TukeyHSD function for non-factors. I think what you really need to do is check the differences between means in different columns (which is not what TuckeyHSD does). You can do this with a simple `t.test`. There are instructions [here](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/inference-about-two-populations/population-mean-between-two-independent-samples).

Comment: how can i plot the interaction or output from TukeyHSD? I ask because I want to accept your answer but I want it to be as representative as possible. Thanks

Comment: I added a way to plot the TukeyHSD object plus a description. There is a plot method for TukeyHSD objects in order to plot it.